# native package refuses to place libraries in the sysroot folder

Tags: yocto, bitbake, openembedded

I have a package (openssl) that must be built for the host and the target. It creates some `.so` and `.a` libraries that some other packages need for runtime and compilation time respectively.

When I compile this package for the target everything works fine and every file ends up in the place I tell it to go, but when I compile for the host (`${PN}-native` target) it just doesn't put the libraries in the host sysroot directory (`./build/tmp/sysroot/x86_64-linux`).

This is the recipe:

```
SUMMARY = "Secure Socket Layer"
SECTION = "libs/network"
LICENSE = "openssl"
LIC_FILES_CHKSUM = "file://LICENSE;md5=4004583eb8fb7f89"

branch = "yocto"
SRC_URI = "git://www.myserver.com/openssl.git;protocol=ssh;branch=${branch}"
SRCREV = "${AUTOREV}"
S = "${WORKDIR}/git"

BBCLASSEXTEND += "native nativesdk"

# This is because I am porting this package from other project and I can't modify it.
FILES_${PN} += "${libdir}/libssl.so ${base_libdir}/libcrypto.so"
FILES_SOLIBSDEV = ""

do_compile() {
    ${MAKE}
}

do_install() {
    DESTDIR=${D} ${MAKE} install
}
```

Could anyone let me know what I am doing wrong? Thanks in advance

Comment: Is there a reason to not use the openssl recipe in OE-Core?

Comment: Yes, I am porting my project from other (very old and hacky) build tool. They have asked me to stick to the packages and build procedure that is being used in the old one. After that, we will start modifying and replacing packages. That's why I am shipping `.so` files.

Comment: Where do you tell the build tool where to install binaries?  It looks like it is assuming that prefix=/usr and you're not telling it otherwise, which is required for native builds as $prefix is how native builds are relocated.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Ok, I know what the problem is:

It seems like for native recipes, you have to install it using the full path to your host sysroot inside the image folder. This means that when compiling for the target, the image folder looks like this:

```
$ tree -d
/openssl/1.0.0-r0/image
├── lib
└── usr
    ├── include
    │   └── openssl
    └── lib
```

but for the host, it looks like this in my case:

```
$ tree -d
openssl-native/1.0.0-r0/image
└── home
    └── xnor
        └── yocto
            └── build
                └── tmp
                    └── sysroots
                        └── x86_64-linux
                            ├── lib
                            └── usr
                                ├── include
                                │   └── openssl
                                └── lib
```

**EDIT**
The right solution is to modify the `Makefile` to take `${prefix}`, `${bindir}`, `${libdir}`, etc. from the environment instead of hardcoding those paths in the `Makefile`. In my case this is not possible because of the project requirements, so I have to do this:

```
SUMMARY = "Secure Socket Layer"
SECTION = "libs/network"
LICENSE = "openssl"
LIC_FILES_CHKSUM = "file://LICENSE;md5=4004583eb8fb7f89"

branch = "yocto"
SRC_URI = "git://www.myserver.com/openssl.git;protocol=ssh;branch=${branch}"
SRCREV = "${AUTOREV}"
S = "${WORKDIR}/git"

BBCLASSEXTEND += "native nativesdk"

# This is because I am porting this package from other project and I can't modify it.
FILES_${PN} += "${libdir}/libssl.so ${base_libdir}/libcrypto.so"
FILES_SOLIBSDEV = ""

do_compile() {
    ${MAKE}
}

do_install() {
    # The change is here!
    DESTDIR=${D}${base_prefix} ${MAKE} install
}
```

and as you can imagine, `${base_prefix}` expands to `"/home/xnor/yocto/build/tmp/sysroots/x86_64-linux/"` for the host (openssl-native) recipe and to `""` for the target (openssl).

Comment: No, for native $D is adjust as appropriate, so that's not correct.

Comment: I think you are wrong, if you have a look to the [manual](http://www.yoctoproject.org/docs/1.8/ref-manual/ref-manual.html#var-D), it clearly states that `${D}` points to `${WORKDIR}/image`

Comment: Exactly.  ${D} is adjusted as appropriate so a standard makefile using DESTDIR will still need to be DESTDIR=${D}, as the build should be respecting ${prefix}.  The problem is that your recipe isn't respecting ${prefix} anywhere.

Comment: @RossBurton I know, the problem is that I cannot modify the makefile. They have hardcoded `prefix = /usr` and that is why it wasn't working. I know my solucion is a hack, but I don't know what else I can do right now!

Comment: You can modify the makefile, with a patch. Just assign a variable and override it when calling make.

Answer (score 1):

First, why are you writing your own recipe for openssl instead of using the one in oe-core?

Anyway the problem is that at no point do you tell the recipe what prefix to use.  In native builds the prefix is what relocates the package correctly into the native sysroot.